# Sqlite unity y android: no such table

Tags: android, base-de-datos, sqlite, unity

Muy buenas ,estoy creando un juego para android utilizando unity mi problema es que la el dispositivo android parece no detectar las tablas de la base de datos mientras que al probarlo directamente en unity si funciona,en principio pensé que tendría algo que ver con las rutas pero si me detecta la base de datos no tendría porque no detectar las tablas.

la captura de la base de datos :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os dejo una captura de el mensaje de error del android device monitor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el texto del error es el siguiente :

```
08-23 19:19:21.987: E/Unity(9636): SQLiteException: no such table: playerDB
08-23 19:19:21.987: E/Unity(9636):   at SQLite4Unity3d.SQLite3.Prepare2 (System.IntPtr db, System.String query) [0x00024] in C:\Users\Aure\1 Plataformer\Assets\Plugins\SQLite4Unity3d\SQLite.cs:3076 
08-23 19:19:21.987: E/Unity(9636):   at SQLite4Unity3d.SQLiteCommand.Prepare () [0x00001] in C:\Users\Aure\1 Plataformer\Assets\Plugins\SQLite4Unity3d\SQLite.cs:2221 
08-23 19:19:21.987: E/Unity(9636):   at SQLite4Unity3d.SQLiteCommand+<ExecuteDeferredQuery>d__12`1[T].MoveNext () [0x00097] in C:\Users\Aure\1 Plataformer\Assets\Plugins\SQLite4Unity3d\SQLite.cs:2136 
08-23 19:19:21.987: E/Unity(9636):   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]..ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] collection) [0x00077] in <c6bd535f6ab848b4a13f34d01b756eef>:0
```

y el codigo :

```
using SQLite4Unity3d;
using UnityEngine;
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
#endif
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class DataService  {

    private SQLiteConnection _connection;
    string DatabaseName="BaseDeDatos.db";
    public DataService(){

#if UNITY_EDITOR
            var dbPath = string.Format(@"Assets/StreamingAssets/{0}", DatabaseName);
#else
        // check if file exists in Application.persistentDataPath
        var filepath = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Application.persistentDataPath, DatabaseName);

        if (!File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            Debug.Log("Database not in Persistent path");
            // if it doesn't ->
            // open StreamingAssets directory and load the db ->

#if UNITY_ANDROID 
            var loadDb = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + DatabaseName);  // this is the path to your StreamingAssets in android
            
            while (!loadDb.isDone) { 
              Debug.Log("aaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            }  // CAREFUL here, for safety reasons you shouldn't let this while loop unattended, place a timer and error check
            // then save to Application.persistentDataPath
            File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, loadDb.bytes);


#endif

            Debug.Log("Database written");
        }

        var dbPath = filepath;
#endif
            _connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create);
        Debug.Log("Final PATH: " + dbPath);   
        

    }



     public int GetPlayerDBCheckPoints(){
       Debug.Log("me quiero morir");   
        
        return _connection.Table<playerDB>().Where(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault().checkpoints;
        
        
    }

  


}
```

Estoy siguiendo este tutorial (https://github.com/robertohuertasm/SQLite4Unity3d) no obstante en el tutorial no aparece este problema,he buscado soluciones pero hasta el momento ninguna ha funcionado,Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

El error:

> SQLiteException: no such table: playerDB

se muestra si la tabla no existe pero también si la base de datos que contiene la tabla no existe o la ruta es incorrecta, la ruta de la base de datos debería ser:

```
/Assets/StreamingAssets/BaseDeDatos.db
```

es demasiado importante asegurar que la base de datos se encuentre en esta estructura y se llame en verdad "BaseDeDatos.db"

Comment: al final conseguí solucionarlo, era todo culpa de que tenia en el móvil instalado una versión antigua porque me pase la apk antigua y por alguna razón eso hacia que no funcionara

Comment: Ok, en esa versión antigua probablemente el  path era incorrecto o no existía la DB.